# No more updates for 32 bit Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04

The new Ubuntu 20.04 version is out , but not for the 32bit computer!
How and from which website do I now update my Ubuntu 32 bit 18.04 version?

Answer (score 5):

See https://ubuntu.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts

- Ubuntu has stopped creating new 32-bit .iso images. The link explains why.
- However, most 32-bit libraries are still being updated, and `do-release-upgrade` still works.

Answer (score 2):

18.04 is a Long Term Support (LTS) version and so will receive updates through the normal automatic update process  until April, 2021. (See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes)

Comment: And [up until 2028](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) with [ESM](https://ubuntu.com/esm), free for up to 3 computers